# How to fetch JSON data dynamically in User interface with out using key name..?

Tags: html, json

I have this JSON format..and want to populate JSON data dynamically in UI with out using key name.

In future when new value will be added in JSON that key value should be displayed in UI with out giving any hard coded value in UI. Please help me out in meeting this scenario.

Your help will be greatly appreciated.

```
[{
    "Title": "card",
    "items": [{
         "count":8,
        "name": "Documentation/Readme.md",
        "SwaggedURL": "https;//card-dev.cfappstpanpz1.ebiz.ver1zon.com/swagger-ui.html",
        "HealthCheckURL": " https://card-dev.cfappslpanpz1.ebiz.verQon.com/health",
        "SecuredHealthCheckURL": " https://card-dev.cfappstpanpz1.ebiz.verizon.com:443/health",
        "HostName": "card.dev.cfappstpanpz1.ebiz.verizon.com",
        "Port": 8080,
        "Status": "UP",
        "UPTime": " 11458792473965 ms",
        "Country":"India"
    }]
}, {
    "Title": "card-details",
    "items": [{
         "count":8,
        "name": "Documentation/Readme.md",
        "SwaggedURL": "https;//card-dev.cfappstpanpz1.ebiz.ver1zon.com/swagger-ui.html",
        "HealthCheckURL": " https://card-dev.cfappslpanpz1.ebiz.verQon.com/health",
        "SecuredHealthCheckURL": " https://card-dev.cfappstpanpz1.ebiz.verizon.com:443/health",
        "HostName": "card.dev.cfappstpanpz1.ebiz.verizon.com",
        "Port": 8080,
        "Status": "UP",
        "UPTime": " 11458792473965 ms"
    }]
}, {
    "Title": "equipment-rack",
    "items": [{
        "count":8,
        "name": "Documentation/Readme.md",
        "SwaggedURL": "https;//card-dev.cfappstpanpz1.ebiz.ver1zon.com/swagger-ui.html",
        "HealthCheckURL": " https://card-dev.cfappslpanpz1.ebiz.verQon.com/health",
        "SecuredHealthCheckURL": " https://card-dev.cfappstpanpz1.ebiz.verizon.com:443/health",
        "HostName": "card.dev.cfappstpanpz1.ebiz.verizon.com",
        "Port": 8080,
        "Status": "UP",
        "UPTime": " 11458792473965 ms"
    }]
}, {
    "Title": "equipment-shelf",
    "items": [{
        "count":8,
        "name": "Documentation/Readme.md",
        "SwaggedURL": "https;//card-dev.cfappstpanpz1.ebiz.ver1zon.com/swagger-ui.html",
        "HealthCheckURL": " https://card-dev.cfappslpanpz1.ebiz.verQon.com/health",
        "SecuredHealthCheckURL": " https://card-dev.cfappstpanpz1.ebiz.verizon.com:443/health",
        "HostName": "card.dev.cfappstpanpz1.ebiz.verizon.com",
        "Port": 8080,
        "Status": "UP",
        "UPTime": " 11458792473965 ms"
    }]
}, {
    "Title": "equip-tplf-create",
    "items": [{
        "count":8,
        "name": "Documentation/Readme.md",
        "SwaggedURL": "https;//card-dev.cfappstpanpz1.ebiz.ver1zon.com/swagger-ui.html",
        "HealthCheckURL": " https://card-dev.cfappslpanpz1.ebiz.verQon.com/health",
        "SecuredHealthCheckURL": " https://card-dev.cfappstpanpz1.ebiz.verizon.com:443/health",
        "HostName": "card.dev.cfappstpanpz1.ebiz.verizon.com",
        "Port": 8080,
        "Status": "UP",
        "UPTime": " 11458792473965 ms"
    }]
}, {
    "Title": "inventory-equip-search",
    "items": [{
        "count":8,
        "name": "Documentation/Readme.md",
        "SwaggedURL": "https;//card-dev.cfappstpanpz1.ebiz.ver1zon.com/swagger-ui.html",
        "HealthCheckURL": " https://card-dev.cfappslpanpz1.ebiz.verQon.com/health",
        "SecuredHealthCheckURL": " https://card-dev.cfappstpanpz1.ebiz.verizon.com:443/health",
        "HostName": "card.dev.cfappstpanpz1.ebiz.verizon.com",
        "Port": 8080,
        "Status": "UP",
        "UPTime": " 11458792473965 ms"
    }]
}, {
    "Title": "port",
    "items": [{
         "count":8,
        "name": "Documentation/Readme.md",
        "SwaggedURL": "https;//card-dev.cfappstpanpz1.ebiz.ver1zon.com/swagger-ui.html",
        "HealthCheckURL": " https://card-dev.cfappslpanpz1.ebiz.verQon.com/health",
        "SecuredHealthCheckURL": " https://card-dev.cfappstpanpz1.ebiz.verizon.com:443/health",
        "HostName": "card.dev.cfappstpanpz1.ebiz.verizon.com",
        "Port": 8080,
        "Status": "UP",
        "UPTime": " 11458792473965 ms"
    }]

}]
```

Comment: You can get all keys of a JavaScript object using https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys.  You can iterate over the resulting array to access the values needed by your UI.

Comment: You'll have to use something else in addition to HTML to what you want...although I'm still not quite sure what you are trying to do...

Comment: How do you want it to be displayed?